# How does Rust call a &dyn Fn?

Tags: assembly, rust, compiler-construction, x86-64

I have this Rust function:

```
pub fn abc(x: &dyn Fn()) {
    x()
}
```

When I compile it with Rust 1.63.0 on [Godbolt Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/o1dWWcdvT) I get this generated x86-64 assembly code:

```
example::abc:
        push    rax
        call    qword ptr [rsi + 40]
        pop     rax
        ret
```

Where is the offset `40` coming from? I want to get an underlying understanding of this generated assembly code.

Comment: Stack Overflow questions need to be self-contained;  quote the source and the asm you're asking about, in code blocks in your question.  The Godbolt link is good, but a link to the code can't be the *only* thing in the question.

Answer (score 11):

`&dyn Fn` is stored as pair of (data, vtable). The vtable contains:

1. A function pointer to `drop_in_place::<Type>`, used to drop the type in e.g. `Box<dyn Trait>` (function pointer sized, `usize` on x86).
2. The size of the data (`usize`).
3. The alignment of the data (`usize`).
4. A list of function pointers to the trait methods, including supertraits. For `Fn` they are:

   1. [`FnOnce::call_once()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html#tymethod.call_once).
   2. [`FnMut::call_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html#tymethod.call_mut).
   3. [`Fn::call()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Fn.html#tymethod.call), which is what we are calling in your code.

So `Fn::call()` is at offset `drop_in_place` (8 bytes) + size (8 bytes) + alignment (8 bytes) + `call_once` (8 bytes) + `call_mut` (8 bytes) = 40 bytes.

Comment: And in the x86-64 System V ABI, a 16-byte object is passed in a pair of registers, so RDI=data, RSI=vtable, already in a register ready to make an indirect call through a vtable entry.